# JQuery returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm doing an calendar, and i created a page to show the events from a certain day.

I'm using Ajax because i dont want my users to reload the page everytime that a new event is created.

So, i'm using Json encode to get the values from an array, and everytime that i print a day with two events, i receive this:

```
[{"event_day":"9","event_name":"test"}, {"event_day":"9","event_name":"test2"}]
```

But when i try to print the elements in JQuery to put inside an element, i receive [object Object]

I inserted the array inside a while loop because i'm getting multiple rows from my database table.

**PHP function**

```
function eventPrint($list_day, $month, $year){

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_day = '".$list_day."' AND event_month = '".$month."' AND event_year = '".$year."'") or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
$event_day = $row['event_day'];
$event_name = $row['event_name'];

   $data[] = array('event_day' => $event_day,
    'event_name' => $event_name
    );

}

echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "modules/groups/new.php",
    data: {
        'list_day': getday,
        'month': getmonth,
        'year': getyear,
        'action': 'selection'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        $('.' + getmonth).html(obj.event_day);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the string representation of an object, so you're trying to use an object somewhere where a string is expected. In other words, `obj.event_day` is an object, and jQuery's `html` doesn't accept plain JS objects as HTML

Comment: I think you need to specify an index for the array, ex obj[0].event_day

Comment: i did that and is working now, thanks ron

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't believe you need the `jQuery.parseJSON()` line. jQuery uses intelligent logic to infer the data type from the MIME type of the response. If you want to explicitly tell jQuery, then simply add `dataType: json` to the `$.ajax({...});` object. Either way, jQuery should handle this for you provided you're not double encoding the string in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice war10ck i will remove this line

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
     success: function( response ) {
     var obj = response[0] ? response : jQuery.parseJSON(response);

     $('.' + getmonth).html(obj[1].event_day);
```